# How to change the position randomly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

```
var imgOut = function(){
    var outImg = Math.floor(Math.random()*slideRandom.length);
    document.getElementById("random").src = imgRandom[outImg];
    var outSlide = slideRandom[outImg]; 
    outSlide();
    var wr = Math.floor(Math.random()*imgRandom.length);
    var btl = Math.floor(Math.random()*bottle.length);

     document.getElementById("bottle2").src = bottle[outImg];
     document.getElementById("bottle1").src = bottle[btl];
     document.getElementById("bottle3").src = bottle[wr];

      /* try below but doesn't work or syntax error occured*/
     var position= ['bottle[outImg]','bottle[btl]','bottle[wr]'];
     var pos = Math.floor(Math.random()*position.length);
     var pos1 = position[pos];
      pos1();   
}
```

what I'm try to do is 
with different arrays to get different each images in different random position.
I've done different images to get but with three different arrays to put in random position doesn't work. what have I done wrong? or how to change above code?

Comment: Several times, you re-write the function you should have called "select item at random from this array" and you do it wrong at least once.  Also, you select (at random) a string and try to execute it as if it were a function.  Solve those two problems and see what happens.

Comment: thanks for answering. understand the put string into an array doesn't work. but didn' catch it what you wrote in fisrt.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your requirements exactly, but consider this code:

```
var setImage = function(id, src) {
   document.getElementById(id).src = src;
};

var chooseOne = function(array) {
   return array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)];
};

var setRandomImages = function() {
   setImage("bottle1", chooseOne(bottle));
   setImage("bottle2", chooseOne(bottle));
   setImage("bottle3", chooseOne(bottle));
};
```

If the array `bottle` is a list of URLs, this will do *something*, though I cannot guarantee it will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var position= ['bottle[outImg]()','bottle[btl]()','bottle[wr]()'];
 var pos = Math.floor(Math.random()*position.length);
 var pos1 = position[pos];
 //pos1();   
 eval( pos1 );
 // or
 (new Function("return pos1"))();
```